# How to handle agile ceremonies for sparsely distributed team members

Tags: agile, scrum-master, distributed-team

We are embarking on a project where the scrum master is in one time zone and overlaps half the team by 2 hours at the start of the day, and the other half of the team by 5.5 hours at the end of the day.

Those two halves never overlap, unless someone from one of them either has a very late day or very early day - neither of which is attractive for an on-going basis.

Is there any advice pm.stex members have for handling this situation?

Comment: You're starting from a faulty premise. How do the two teams coordinate and hand off work to one another? Make that explicit, and your Scrum ceremonies will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recommendation:** Split the team in into 2 teams
**Goal:** Team doesn't have to take hit of staying late / coming early
**Prerequisite:** Stories teams going to work should be independent as much as possible.
**Cons:** Scrum Master has to repeat the ceremonies for both the teams.
**Risk:** Team alignment on work progress / status
**Risk Mitigation:** 
Scrum Master shares the Work status / progress with both the teams.
Weekly once both team leads / entire team catch up to clear the gaps if any.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, you can have the team members (or ScrumMaster) capture the standup entries on a dedicated slack channel (or your team communication tool) so that the other team can read it when they come online

Answer (score -1):

Might I suggest recording the stand-ups if possible, record the 1st team (we use Skype for business) and play it back on for the 2nd team. Any updates can be emailed to the 1st team.

Planning and Reviews / retros will be more difficult, but a similar approach can be adopted.

But even as I type this I'm wondering ,,, how can they be one team if they **never** cross each others path? perhaps running them as separate teams is the way to go.